# Listen to all voice mails on iPhone continuously

Tags: iphone, voicemail

On older phones I could start vmail going and just let it run - through all messages. There were options to perform actions as you went along. But if you just let it go it would play all messages and save them.

I miss that:on the iPhone I have to mess with the keys for every message. The "speaker" , play/pause and go back are all v close to one another so it is frustrating. Also there is a few seconds of pause for the vmail to be retrieved - for each vmail.

Is there any way to get the behavior of the older phones for vmail playback on the iPhone?  Essentially a hands-free full playback?

thanks

Comment: Have a look at YouMail, HulloMail, Google Voice and VisionMail Visual Voicemail. I'm not sure, whether or not they are capable of what you are expecting, but you can give them a try. The build in visual voice mail functionality of iOS won't match your expectations anytime.

Comment: @pallox  I think you're on to the right track. Pls make this an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As you wish, changing from comment to answer:*
Have a look at YouMail, HulloMail, Google Voice and VisionMail Visual Voicemail. I'm not sure, whether or not they are capable of what you are expecting, but you can give them a try. The build in visual voice mail functionality of iOS won't match your expectations anytime.

Also have a look at the answer of @Margaret Martin. @Marc Wilson also provided a useful approach. :)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Voicemail—where you can select which message you want to listen to instead of being forced to listen to them in a specific order—doesn't seem to allow continuous playback. Also, is suspect that the delay in retrieving a message is because it's contacting the carrier.

It may be possible to find an app that allows playback as you want, but beware of buying a an older app that may not work with more recent iOS versions or one that won't work with your carrier.

I don't know what version of iOS you're running, but more recent versions (I'm looking at 10.2) have an improved interface for playback as well as transcription of the message.

Comment: _doesn't seem to allow continuous playback_ guessing that's the clue. It isn't designed for continous playback, since you are allowed to choose the message you want to hear.

Answer (score 3):

Of course.  Dial into your provider's voicemail system and use it as you like.  That's what it's there for.

Visual Voicemail is there for random access to your voicemails.